# Struts 1 redirect from action to action with parameters as POST request

Tags: java, post, struts

now am trying to redirect to action class from action class with some parameters in my Struts 1.3 web application,
here is my code

```
ActionRedirect redirect = new ActionRedirect(mapping.findForward(forwardPage));
redirect.addParameter("method", forwardPage);   
redirect.addParameter("username", "user");
redirect.addParameter("password", "PWD");
redirect.addParameter("forwardPage", "success");        
return redirect;
```

it's working fine, but all parameters are showed in address bar, **how can i redirect it as POST request parameter(hide parameters)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, it is not a Struts problem. It is how HTTP is designed. When a browser is redirected, it perform a `GET` request. You cannot ask the browser to do a `POST` instead. The only way would be to add some Javascript to send the request.

Or you can also ask Struts to do an internal redirection but it will be hidden to the client and the url will not change.

Comment: thank u gma, how internal redirection could do? can u give some idea plz?

Comment: with a simple `return actionMapping.findForward(...)` in your action, by default struts perform internal redirection, if you want an explicit (by browser) redirection you have to put `redirect=true` in your forward mapping.